# python - how to remove lists which have duplicate elements in nested lists

Tags: python

If I have a list of lists like so:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [1,2], [6,7]]
```

How do I remove list elements such that the nested lists with even a few elements are duplicated are removed? The resulting list should just be:

```
a = [[4,5],[6,7]]
```

Comment: Hint: instead of trying to identify nested lists that don't share elements with other nested lists, find the elements that are shared (by counting their occurrences), and then identify lists that don't contain any of those elements.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is conceptually similar to one proposed by *Julien* but has a different implementation.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
a = [[1,2,1], [4,5], [1,2], [6,7]]
```

Calculate the set of duplicates. If two items are repeated only within a sublist, they are not considered dups. First, get a counter of all items.

```
counter = Counter(chain(*map(set, a)))
#Counter({2: 2, 1: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 3: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1})
dups = {val for val, count in counter.items() if count > 1}
#{1,2}
```

Intersect the duplicates with each sublist  and filter *out* the duped sublists:

```
list(filter(lambda sublist: not dups & set(sublist), a))
#[[4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

It works both for lists of lists and lists of tuples.

Comment: FYI this wont work if input list is `a = [[1,1,2],[4,5],[8,9],[6,7]]`.

Comment: @bro-grammer Cool catch. Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: Thats pretty quick. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [1,2], [6,7]]

# count how many times each item appears
count = defaultdict(int)
for l in a:
    for x in l:
        count[x] += 1

# keep only sublists where all element have a count of 1
[l for l in a if all(count[x] < 2 for x in l)]
```

Comment: You can build the `count` in one line as `collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*a))`.

Comment: can you please add description as well with your solution, it will help others to understand more effectively.  Last line of your answer needs to explain

Comment: @DyZ well 2 lines because you need to import itertools too ;)... Unless you do it with  `Counter(sum(a, []))`

Comment: Thanks! However, what if "a" it's a list of tuples instead? Does that still work?

Comment: @darrrn Yes just the same.

Comment: FYI this doesn't work if input list if `a = [[1,1,2],[4,5],[8,9],[6,7]]`

Comment: @bro-grammer who knows? this edge case is not clear, the OP doesn't mention what should happen to [1,1,2], assuming it should be kept is a stretch, and if not I'm not sure why you say it's not working...

Comment: When i say it doesn't work i mean that your solution will remove `[1,1,2]` from the list even none of the element of this sublist is duplicate in other sublist. I believe this is the primary part of this question and doesn't require any explanation.

Comment: @bro-grammer from OP "even a few elements are duplicated are removed" there is absolutely no mention that duplication within the same list don't count, so why assuming [1,1,2] should be kept?

Comment: You are missing something here _NESTED LIST with even a few elements are duplicated_

Comment: I think the edge case is unclear and only OP can clarify if [1,1,2] is to be kept or not,  "NESTED LIST" doesn't add any further clarification.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the intersection of each sublist with rest of the elements of list, if all of the intersections are empty then the element is not repeated

```
>>> d = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [1,2], [6,7]]
>>> [a for a in d if all(len(set(a) & set(b)) == 0 for b in d if b!=a)]
>>> [[4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

Comment: Probably the most inefficient way to solve this problem... (not the downvoter however)

Comment: @darrrn It works, but it does not work _great_. Learn to use "good Python." It's a good investment. (Not the downvoter.)

Comment: @DyZ sorry but I'm still new to python. Could you explain why this is not good code? Thank you!

Comment: As @Julien suggested, this code is computationally inefficient.